# Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0' only on remote server. Works on local

Tags: .net, development-environment, .net-standard-2.0

As our development team have upgraded our project to support a special form of caching, our .NET project no longer works when put in an environment that isn't a local machine. I tried to figure out how to install .NET standard  on the server, but only came across [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/09/20/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/), which is still on a local machine.

I have looking around and have consulted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50000669/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0) on Stack Overflow, [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/328) on GitHub and a bunch of other sites, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [**.NET framework 4.7.1**](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) on the server (it was running 4.6.1) and now it works just fine. I hope this will save someone some trouble